# Fetch Posts Based on Multiple Ratings foreach Taxonomy

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am setting ratings of posts based on the taxonomies, lets say, now i want to query them based on ratings and taxonomies.

an app on PC has rating 10. (meta_key=rating_pc)

an app on Android has rating 5. (meta_key=rating_android)

```
add_action( 'posts_where', 'minscoreaction' );
function minscoreaction( $sql ){

    global $wpdb;
    $minscore = 9;//get_query_var( 'minscore' );
    $platformslug = 'pc';//get_query_var( 'platformlist' );

    if( $minscore ){
        $sql .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND ( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key LIKE %s AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE %s )", "rating_".$platformslug.'%',$minscore.'%');
```

**PROBLEM**: I am getting nothing... means no post. And actually one post exist with rated 9 for pc.

**NOTE**: I can only use this method to Query Post due to several reasons.

**ANOTHER NOTE:**

```
$where .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND $wpdb->posts.post_type LIKE %s ", 'reviews%' );
```

This returns all the reviews Post Type 


But This returns nothing

```
$where .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE %s ", '9%' );
```

[image: Meta Value with 9]

**FRONT-END**

```
print_r(query_posts('post_type=reviews&platformlist=pc&minscore=9'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in `functions.php`  or your `template page` where you want to use.

```
    function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
       global $wpdb;
        $minscore = 9;
        $platformslug = 'pc';    
        $posttype =     "reviews";

$where .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_type = '".$posttype."')";
$where .= " AND (($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key LIKE '_overall_rating_".$platformslug."%' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '".$minscore."')) ";

       return $where;
    }
    add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

OR with **`WP_QUERY`**

use this code on **frontend**.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => $posttype ,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array('key' => '_overall_rating_' . $platformslug,
            'value' => $minscore)
    )
));
print_r($the_query);
```

Comment: can you edit your question with full source code, also check meta_value doesnot contains spaces. with `9`

Comment: i have just updated the question..using same method $wpdb->posts is working fine.. but not $wpdb->postmeta

Comment: the wildcard `%` doesnot work with `wp_postmeta` until you give the correct key which is `'_overall_rating_".$platformslug."%'` also i have edited my answer with the current key you have in `wp_postmeta` as per the Screen shot.

Comment: Yes i was using the same key, above code was just example. also i have removed wildcard, i tried to display only those reviews which has meta_key '9' regardless of key.. still an empty array()...

Comment: you are mistaken at frontend , you should use WP_QUERY($argument_array).

Comment: Thanks WP_QUERY Solved it for me.. i will also test the above one which will really help me integrating with 3rd party theme ajax loop.